# "no module named _base" on __init__.py soaplib django 1.10 and python 3.4.3

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have this problem when i enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/books in the browser.

```
No module named '_base'
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/books
Django Version:     1.7.9
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named '_base'
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/soaplib-2.0.0b2.post0-py3.4.egg/soaplib/core/__init__.py in <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/khaled/Bureau/soaplib-django-master',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/soaplib-2.0.0b2.post0-py3.4.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages']"
```

Any help regarding the same would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your title says you are using Django 1.10, but the traceback clearly says that you are running Django 1.7.9.

Comment: how to use django 1.10,  because I installed latest version and i don't have any idea how running 1.7.9 and not running 1.10

Comment: If you are using a virtualenv, then you need to switch into the virtual environment before you install Django. If you are not using a virtualenv, then install with `pip3` instead of pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if [soaplib](https://github.com/soaplib/soaplib) is unmaintained, the recommendation appears to be to use [spyne](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/) instead.

Your title says you are using Django 1.10, but the traceback says you are using 1.7.9.

If you are using a virtualenv, upgrade with:

```
pip install --upgrade 'django<1.11'
```

Or if you are not using a virtualenv, use pip3 instead of pip.

```
pip3 install --upgrade 'django<1.11'
```

Comment: thanks ,Django 1.10 it's work and soaplib it's work too and i find file WSDL but how to call this web service soap and to use his function and thanks

Comment: I'm glad it's working. How to call the web services sounds like a separate issue, so you ask a new question. You'll need to provide more information that the comment above.